# R - SARIMA fitted function returns NULL

Tags: r, arima

As part of my class, I have to study and forecast Atlanta airport trafic. The whole model is validated. The only issue is that I must plot fitted values to the actual values in order to analyze residuals.
However, my SARIMA model returns an object NULL when using fitted function..

The dataset can be uploaded using [Github repository](https://github.com/pcliquot/atlantaairtrafic)

Could you please tell me where is the issue ?

```
####################################################
##================================================##
##     Traffic at Atlanta Airport 2003-2019       ##
##================================================##
####################################################



# The purpose of this project is to forecast Atlanta Airport future traffic
# following the Box-Jenkins Methodology



## Import Data
#-------------
Atl.Traff <- read.csv2("AtlantaTraffic_2003-2019.csv")

## Convert the raw data into a time series
#-----------------------------------------
Atl.Traff.ts <- ts(Atl.Traff[,3], start=c(2003,1), frequency=12)


## Loading all the needed packages
#---------------------------------
library(tseries)
library(TSA)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)



#-----------------------------------
## Step 0 : Stationarization of data
#===================================


## Plot raw data time series
#---------------------------
plot.ts(Atl.Traff.ts, main="")
abline(reg=lm(Atl.Traff.ts~time(Atl.Traff.ts)), col="red") 
# There is a positive trend
plot(decompose(Atl.Traff.ts))
monthplot(Atl.Traff.ts)
# There is seasonality
acf(ts(Atl.Traff.ts,frequency=1))
pacf(ts(Atl.Traff.ts, frequency=1))
#The time series isn't stationary : positive trend, seasonality and 
#the series is not decaying fast to 0
adf.test(diff(Atl.Traff.ts), alternative = "stationary")

## Log transformation : reduce increasing variance
#-------------------------------------------------
l.Atl.Traff.ts <- log(Atl.Traff.ts)
plot(cbind(Atl.Traff.ts,l.Atl.Traff.ts), main='Traffic and log tansformation')
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(ts(l.Atl.Traff.ts,frequency=1)) #The series doesn't decay fast to 0
pacf(ts(l.Atl.Traff.ts, frequency=1))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#We haven't reached stationarity but at least, it reduces the increasing variance effect


## Remove the trend : 1st order difference
#-----------------------------------------
dl.Atl.Traff.ts <- diff(l.Atl.Traff.ts,1) 
plot(dl.Atl.Traff.ts)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(ts(dl.Atl.Traff.ts, frequency=1), main="ACF : 1st order difference") 
pacf(ts(dl.Atl.Traff.ts, frequency=1), main="PACF : 1st order difference")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

## Remove the seasonality : difference of order 12
#-------------------------------------------------
dl.Atl.Traff.ts_12 <- diff(dl.Atl.Traff.ts,12)
plot(dl.Atl.Traff.ts_12) #We observe some extreme values
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(ts(dl.Atl.Traff.ts_12,frequency=1), main="ACF : difference of order 12")
pacf(ts(dl.Atl.Traff.ts_12, frequency=1), main="PACF : difference of order 12")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))


#--------------------------------------------------
## Step 1 : Determining ARMA order parameters (p,q)
#==================================================


# fit a multiplicative SARIMA on l.Atl.Traff.ts
# d=D=1: transformations performed on l.Atl.Traff.ts


# q, Q: MA part (ACF)
# q = 1
# Q = 1


# p,P: AR part (PACF)
# p=2 
# P=1



#----------------------------------
## Step 2 : Coefficients estimation
#==================================


## Build a model SARIMA(2,1,1)(1,1,1) s=12
#-----------------------------------------
model <- arima(l.Atl.Traff.ts, c(2,1,1), seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,1), period=12), method='ML')
model
#aic = -820.63


## Plot of the fitted value
#--------------------------
fit <- fitted(model)
plot.ts(cbind(l.Atl.Traff.ts,fit),plot.type='single',col=c('black','red'))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please reduce this to a minimal example and put the input data right in the question  so that if it idisappears from the net the question and answers will still be usable. Reduce the code and input as much as possible while still providing enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found out the answer of my issue. TSA and forecast libraries conflict each other. When using fitted function, you should unload TSA package.

Comment: instead of unloading force the use of `forcast` by using `forcast::fitted`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer